# List items into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

Trying to figure out how to get an decent array out of "var fonts". Purpose would be to have an random texts in input value. At the moment it will output just an long row of texts together (Text1Text2text3text4andsoon).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fonts = [];
    $(".oppa").each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).find("li").text();
        //alert(txt);
        fonts.push(txt);
    });

    alert(fonts);

    var time = setInterval(function() {
       var newFont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*fonts.length)];
       $('#uwpqsf_id_key').attr('value', newFont);
    }, 1000);

    $('#uwpqsf_id_key').hover(function(ev){
        clearInterval(time);
    }, function(ev){
        time = setInterval(function() {
           var newFont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*fonts.length)];
           $('#uwpqsf_id_key').attr('value', newFont);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are getting the text of all your "li" elements altogether into the "txt" variable. Thus, "fonts" is an array of length 1.

You need to loop over each of you list item to properly build the "fonts" array. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fonts = [];

  $(".oppa").each(function(){
       $(this).find("li").each(function(){
           fonts.push($(this).text());
       });
  });

  alert(fonts.length);  // fonts is now an array with length equal to your number of list items

  /* Rest of your code goes here */

});
```

Best.